# Jquery tabs not rendering

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs

I am using jquery to create two sets of tabs on a page. The tabs display images when clicked. The first set of tabs renders fine but the second set of tabs does not render. Here is the html:

```
<div id="ecimgtabs">
<ul>
<li id="first"><a href="#ltec1">IMAGEI</a></li>
<li id="second"><a href="#ltec2">IMAGEII</a></li>   
</ul>
<div id="ltec1">
<img src="path"></img>
</div>
<div id="ltec2">
<img src="path"></img>
</div>
</div>


<div id="ecimgtabs">
<ul>
<li id="first"><a href="#stec1">IMAGEI </a></li>
<li id="second"><a href="#stec2">IMAGEII </a></li>  
</ul>
<div id="stec1">
<img src="path"></img>
</div>
<div id="stec2">
<img src="path"></img>
</div>
</div>
```

Here's the jquery script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var tabdiv = $('#ecimgtabs div');
$('#ecimgtabs div').hide();
$('#ecimgtabs div:first').show();
$('#ecimgtabs ul li:first').addClass('selected');

$('#ecimgtabs ul li a').click(function(){
$('#ecimgtabs ul li').removeClass('selected');
$(this).parent().addClass('selected');
var currentTab = $(this).attr('href');
$('#ecimgtabs div').hide();
$(currentTab).show();
return false;
});
});
```

Comment: Indents help other people read your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I was able to figure this out. I changed the div IDs to be separate. So the 1st div changed to lecimgtabs and the next one secimgtabs. I am sure you could do it with identical IDs but this worked for me.Here's the updated code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function()
{
jQuery('.lecimgtabs div:odd').hide();
jQuery('.secimgtabs div:odd').hide();
jQuery('.lecimgtabs ul li:even').addClass('selected');
jQuery('.secimgtabs ul li:even').addClass('selected');

jQuery('.lecimgtabs ul li a').click(function(){
jQuery('.lecimgtabs ul li').removeClass('selected');
jQuery(this).parent().addClass('selected');
var currentTab = jQuery(this).attr('href');
 if(currentTab=='#ltec2')
 {
    jQuery('.lecimgtabs div#ltec1').hide();
 }
 else
 {
    jQuery('.lecimgtabs div#ltec2').hide();
 }

jQuery(currentTab).show();
return false;
});


jQuery('.secimgtabs ul li a').click(function(){
jQuery('.secimgtabs ul li').removeClass('selected');
jQuery(this).parent().addClass('selected');
var currentTab = jQuery(this).attr('href');
 if(currentTab=='#stec2')
 {
    jQuery('.secimgtabs div#stec1').hide();
 }
 else
 {
    jQuery('.secimgtabs div#stec2').hide();
 }

jQuery(currentTab).show();
return false;
});
});
```

@kyle there was no issue with the css.

Answer (score 1):

You have two divs with the same ID: `ecimgtabs`, So jQuery will only recognize the first  one in the DOM. Try switching to a class

```
<div class="ecimgtabs">
<ul>
<li id="first"><a href="#ltec1">IMAGEI</a></li>
<li id="second"><a href="#ltec2">IMAGEII</a></li>   
</ul>
<div id="ltec1">
<img src="path"></img>
</div>
<div id="ltec2">
<img src="path"></img>
</div>
</div>


<div class="ecimgtabs">
<ul>
<li id="first"><a href="#stec1">IMAGEI </a></li>
<li id="second"><a href="#stec2">IMAGEII </a></li>  
</ul>
<div id="stec1">
<img src="path"></img>
</div>
<div id="stec2">
<img src="path"></img>
</div>
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var tabdiv = $('#ecimgtabs div');
$('.ecimgtabs div').hide();
$('.ecimgtabs div:first').show();
$('.ecimgtabs ul li:first').addClass('selected');

$('.ecimgtabs ul li a').click(function(){
$('.ecimgtabs ul li').removeClass('selected');
$(this).parent().addClass('selected');
var currentTab = $(this).attr('href');
$('.ecimgtabs div').hide();
$(currentTab).show();
return false;
});
});
```

Comment: Kyle, Erik, So I changed the div to a class and here is what is happening. When the page loads the first set of tabs loads fully with images and one image selected. The second set of tabs only loads the tabs, no image is seen or selected.

Comment: Sorry hit enter accidentally and submitted the unfinished comment. Anyway, when I click on the second set of tabs, the second set of images load and images under the first set of tabs disappear. So, now I have a partially loaded first set and fully loaded second set. When I click on the partially loaded first set the reverse happens and so on.